# Data Augmentation model doesnt learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Hi i am trying to train a CNN model. While without data augmentation i get like 60 val_Acc. i am trying to augment data for a better acc however my model doesn't seems to be learning augmented accuracy dont pass 12. i dont get what the problem is

```
`batch_size=8
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
            width_shift_range=0.1,
            height_shift_range=0.1,
            horizontal_flip= True,
        
    )
data_gen.fit(x_train, augment=True)
train_gen = data_gen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size)
steps_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size


r = model.fit(data_gen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32),
              validation_data=(x_test,y_test),
              steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs = 15,
              verbose=1)`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> **Data Augmentation help in making Model more Generalized.**
>  If your
> model is facing problem of overfitting then you can use Data
> Augmentation Technique.
>  The Better Accuracy of Model can be
> expected on Testing Dataset if Data Augmentation is used.
>
> **In case if model accuracy is low or not improving-**
>  Consider
> changing the model structure along with optimizers and change learning
> rate. Test different version of model and select the best one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).